# C# XML Serialization not working as intended

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this class model here:

```cs
    public class Config
    {
        public ConnectionConfig ConnectionConfig { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="advanced")]
        public bool AdvancedEnabled { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConnectionConfig
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "instance")]
        public List<InstanceConfig> Instances { get; set; }
    }

    public class InstanceConfig
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Uri { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Serialized it is this XML:

```xml
<config advanced="false">
  <ConnectionConfig>
    <instance username="user1" password="123">http://localhost:1234</instance>
    <instance username="user2" password="1234">http://localhost:1235</instance>
    <instance username="user3" password="12345">http://localhost:1236</instance>
  </ConnectionConfig>
</config>
```

But I want to have a XML like this:

```xml
<config advanced="false">
    <instance username="user1" password="123">http://localhost:1234</instance>
    <instance username="user2" password="1234">http://localhost:1235</instance>
    <instance username="user3" password="12345">http://localhost:1236</instance>
</config>
```

So basically without "ConnectionConfig". But in my model I need "ConnectionConfig" as an own object.

What am I missing or not understanding?

I tried to move the `[XmlElement(ElementName = "instance")]` attribute to `ConnectionConfig` but still not my desired output.

Comment: Passwords should not be stored in any format that is human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified it, but I think you might need to decorate the `ConnectionConfig` property to indicate that it is an element in its own right.

```
public class Config
{
    [XmlElement("ConnectionConfig")]
    public ConnectionConfig ConnectionConfig { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="advanced")]
    public bool AdvancedEnabled { get; set; }
}
```